# Series convergence proof

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a^2_n$ be a convergent series. Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|a_n|}{n}$ converges.

Should I use \begin{equation}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|a_n|}{n} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt{\frac{a^2_n}{n^2}}\end{equation}and go on from there?

Pretty confused about this. How to approach such a problem?

Comment: Do you know the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: prove the more general fact that if $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2$ and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty b_n^2$ converge, then $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n b_n$ converges.

Then set $b_n = \frac{1}{n}, \forall n\geq1$.

Comment: It is doubtful if OP knows C-S inequality. So this is no answer at all.